# TextInputLayout подсветить кооректно заполненные поля

Tags: android, material-design, textinputlayout

Делаю форму регистрации в приложении в котором есть несколько полей:

1. Имя
2. Фамилия
3. Номер телефона
4. Пароль
5. Подтверждение пароля

В качестве полей ввода я использую TextInputLayout + TextInputEditText. Задача состоит в следующем: мне нужно у корректно заполненных полей подсветить border черным цветом. Если поле пустое, то оно должно быть серым. А если ошибка то красным.

Пробовал применить селектор следующего вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#000000" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="#7E7E7E" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="#454545" />

</selector>
```

со свойством app:boxStrokeColor="@color/selector_box_stroke"

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_phone"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/selector_box_stroke"> <!-- задаем цвет border -->

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="hint" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

и в коде пробовал у этих текстовых полей менять свойство isSelected = true. По итогу окрашивался только тот элемент, на котором был фокус. Остальные заполненные поля по итогу имели цвет border по-умолчанию.

Есть ли какое либо решение?